# Disabling the Azure AD cloud only account?

Tags: entra-id, entra-domain-services

Folks,

I wonder what's the command or the steps in Azure Portal to disable not deleting Azure AD Cloud only account?

Because so far I can only delete the account and resetting the password, but not disabling the Azure AD account like in the OnPremise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the first example in this article - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0

Comment: that's great, thanks, Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As joeqwerty says you can use the PowerShell Set-MsolUser. Or there is a GUI method.

- After selecting the user in Azure AD portal https://portal.azure.com/
- Select Profile under the Manage section on the left
- Click the Edit button
- Under the Settings section set "Block sign in" to Yes
- Click Save at the top

[image]
[image]

Comment: that's great, thanks Phil.